# How to pause an animation with OpenGL / glut

Tags: opengl, animation, graphics, glut

To achieve an animation, i am just redrawing things on a loop.

However, I need to be able to pause when a key is pressed. I know the way i'm doing it now its wrong because it eats all of my cycles when the loop is going on.

Which way is better, and will allow for a key pause and resume?

I tried using a bool flag but obviously it didnt change the flag until the loop was done.

Comment: Do you mean that your entire game runs in a loop or the animations themselves are little loops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the correct very basic architecture sorted in that the everything needs to be updated in a loop, but you need to make your loop a lot smarter for a game (or other application requiring OpenGL animations).

> However, I need to be able to pause when a key is pressed.

A basic way of doing this is to have a boolean value `paused` and to wrap the game into a loop.

```
while(!finished) {
    while(!paused) {
        update();
        render();
    }
}
```

Typically however you still want to do things such as look at your inventory, craft things, etc. while your game is paused, and many games still run their main loop while the game's paused, they just don't let the actors know any time has passed. For instance, it sounds like your animation frames simply have a number of game-frames to be visible for. This is a bad idea because if the animation speed increases or decreases on a different computer, the animation speed will look wrong on those computers. You can consider my answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16463/commonizing-cycle-time-across-different-browsers-for-html5/16464#16464), and the linked samples to see how you can achieve framerate-independent animation by specifying animation frames in terms of millisecond duration and passing in the frame time in the update loop. For instance, your main game then changes to look like this:

```
float previousTime = 0.0f;
float thisTime = 0.0f;
float framePeriod = 0.0f;

while(!finished) {
    thisTime = getTimeInMilliseconds();
    framePeriod = previousTime - thisTime;

    update(framePeriod);
    render();

    previousTime = thisTime;
}
```

Now, everything in the game that gets updated will know how much time has passed since the previous frame. This is helpful for all your physics calculations as all of our physical formulae are in terms of time + starting factors + decay factors (for instance, the SUVAT equations). The same information can be used for your animations to make them framerate independent as I have described with some links to examples [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/whats-the-best-way-to-create-animations-when-doing-android-development/18006#18006).

To answer the next part of the question:

```
it eats all of my cycles when the loop is going on.
```

This is because you're using 100% of the CPU and never going to sleep. If we consider that we want for instance 30fps on the target device (and we know that this is possible) then we know the period of one frame is 1/30th of a second. We've just calculated the time it takes to update and render our game, so we can sleep for any of the spare time:

```
float previousTime = 0.0f;
float thisTime = 0.0f;
float framePeriod = 0.0f;
float availablePeriod = 1 / 30.0f;

while (!finished) {
    thisTime = getTimeInMilliseconds();
    framePeriod = previousTime - thisTime;

    update(framePeriod);
    render();

    previousTime = thisTime;

    if (framePeriod < availablePeriod)
        sleep(availablePeriod - framePeriod);
}
```

This technique is called framerate governance as you are manually controlling the rate at which you are rendering and updating.

Comment: Right now I have something similar, like if(complete)... But for some reason the MouseEvent doesnt change my flag while i am on my loop. The only thing I see different on yoru code than mine is that your update function is isolated in a update(function) and mine is inside my loop.  Your code addresses the CPU eating issue, but I need some help on the mouse event (or keyboard). Could you expand a little bit?

Comment: @Andre Are you sure that your mouse event handler is being called? You've checked with a debugger that it changes the pause boolean *and that that change is visible in your main loop*? There might be a scoping issue here.

Comment: it does change the flag, but not while its doing my main animation loop. I could possibly be because its using all the cycles to do the loop and doesnt get to do my mousevent. Does it sound like a reasonable deduction?

Comment: @Andre if they're in the same thread then it's possible yes, but I'd have thought that if your event listener is being called then that's not it. Are you sure you don't have a scoping problem, are you shadowing any variable names? Maybe you could update your question with a very basic code sample.

Comment: I ended up using a timed function as an 'animation step' and when the step was done it would allow my mouse and keyboard event listeners to run, and then my flag changed before entering the next step animation. `void Timed(int)
{

 update();
 glutTimerFunc(10, Timed, 5);
}`